# TypeError: Cannot read property 'rotation' of undefined - three.js

Tags: three.js

Im trying to make newtons cradle and to move balls. And i get error. Here is whole code https://notepad.pw/s1lozjcy 
I know the angles are not relevant.

```
var tiltDirection = 1;
function render() {
    ball5.animated.rotation.x += tiltDirection * 0.5 * Math.PI/180;
    if(ball5.animated.rotation.x > 103 * Math.PI/180){
        tiltDirection = -1;
    ball5.animated.rotation.x = 2*(103 * Math.PI/180) - ball5.animated.rotation.x;
    }else if(ball5.animated.rotation.x < -22 * Math.PI/180){
        tiltDirection = 1;
    ball5.animated.rotation.x = 2* (-22 * Math.PI/180) - ball5.animated.rotation.x;
        }
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Should ball5.animated.rotation be ball5.rotation ?

Comment: Ok, now i get "Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive." I cant move with mouse through window.

Comment: Start up a new question or Google it :)